# Target specific Excel workbook by name with Python with win32com

Tags: python, excel, windows, com, win32com

If I have multiple Excel workbooks open on Windows 10, and I'm using win32com in Python, is there a way to choose a workbook by name? So far, I have been using:

```
ExcelApp = win32com.client.GetActiveObject('Excel.Application')
wb = ExcelApp.Workbooks(2)
```

but that requires the correct workbook to be the second one. Is there some way I can do it by name or filepath instead? I tried:

```
ExcelApp = win32com.client.GetActiveObject('Excel.Application')
wb = ExcelApp.Workbooks.Open(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'myworkbook.xlsm'))
```

but this does not work either if I have multiple Excel workbooks open. It ends up choosing the wrong workbook since later on, when it is looking for a specific sheet by name, it cannot find it.

If I try:

```
ExcelApp = win32com.client.GetActiveObject('Excel.Application')
wb = ExcelApp.Workbooks('My Workbook Name')
```

I get this:

````
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Archives\mypyscript.py", line 79, in <module>
    wb = ExcelApp.Workbooks('My Workbook Name')
  File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\gen_py\3.8\00020813-0000-0000-C000-000000000046x0x1x9\Workbooks.py", line 198, in __call__
    ret = self._oleobj_.InvokeTypes(0, LCID, 2, (13, 0), ((12, 1),),Index
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, None, None, None, 0, -2147352565), None)```
````

Comment: Does `wb = ExcelApp.Workbooks('yourworkbookname')` not work?

Comment: Try including the file extension: `'MyWorkbookName.xlsx'` or similar.

Comment: @BigBen, that solved it, thank you!